# How to publish my unit tests with my python package

Tags: python, packaging

How can I publish my tests along with my package?  I want to keep my tests separate from src, as below.

```
mypackage/
    src/
        mypackage/
            __init__.py
            hello.py
    tests/
        test_hello.py
```

And the content of my `setup.cfg` is:

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 1.5.0
author = John Henckel
url = https://test.com
[options]
package_dir =
    = src
packages = find:
[options.packages.find]
where = src
```

However when I do `build + twine` the tests are not included.  Is there a way to include the tests in the tar and wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears people put the `tests/` folder inside the module directory when they want to distribute them along with the code.

[Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341006/where-should-i-put-tests-when-packaging-python-modules).

You can see the project structure they use [here](https://the-hitchhikers-guide-to-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/creation.html#arranging-your-file-and-directory-structure).

Edit:
[This link](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#setting-up-setup-py) suggests that you just have to list the directories in your `setup.py`

```py
    packages=['an_example_pypi_project', 'tests'],
```

I cannot find anything about setup.cfg though I would imagine it should be the same.

Comment: Thanks indeed that works. If I make the tests to be a subdirectory under src/mypackage, then it gets published. However, I don't want to do that. I was hoping there is some magic I can put into the `setup.cfg` that will act *as if* the tests is under src/mypackage without actually moving it there.

Comment: Both of those links are from 2009. I tried adding tests to the list of packages, and it works badly.  After the user does `pip install mypackage` the `tests` directory is directly under `site-packages`!! so if two packages have tests, the second one will clobber the first! BTW, I think it is astonishing that `pip` does not prevent this from happening, or even show a warning. It would be easy for a rogue package to use the same directory name as another package and clobber it. It is stupid that 'pip' does not do a better job to isolate the packages from each other.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution, but as a hack I have decided to just copy the `tests` directory into the `src/mypackage` (temporarily, just before the build) as part of the continuous integration pipeline. My build pipeline script looks like this:

```
git clone https://.../mypackage
cd mypackage
pip install pytest -r requirements.txt
pytest
pip install build twine
cp -R tests src/mypackage
python -m build --wheel
twine upload ... dist/*.whl
```

and this works just fine. After this I can `pip install mypackage` and run the tests by navigating to the package root (under site-packages) and running `pytest`.

The pytest [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/usage.html) says I should also be able to do `pytest --pyargs mypackage`. But that does not work. I don't know why. Bug in pytest?