# Where to put unittests in a python project package?

Tags: python, unit-testing, package

I want to create a python package, but I am not sure what the best place for the unittest directory is. In the [Hitchhikers Guide](http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html) the tests are put inside the actual module, as well as [here](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html?nojs=1), while the [Python Project HowTo](http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/) advocates putting them in an extra directory on project level.

So should the project be layed out as this (Format A):

```
MyProject/
  |-- setup.py
  |-- README
  |-- mypackage/
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- some_module.py
       |-- test/
            |-- __init__.py
            |-- test_module.py
  |-- scripts/
       |-- script1.py
```

or like this (Format B):

```
MyProject/
  |-- setup.py
  |-- README
  |-- mypackage/
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- some_module.py
  |-- test/
       |-- __init__.py
       |-- test_module.py
  |-- scripts/
       |-- script1.py
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages in either case? Is this defined somewhere?

I want to use distutils(2) for the packaging (setup.py and/or setup.cfg) so it could be especially important under these circumstances how to structure the tests. In Format A the unittests will be included automaticaly in the package (if the package as a whole is defined) while for Format B the unittests must be specified in a separate way (which I even do not know).

Comment: There are a lot of opinions on where to put tests, check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151/where-do-the-python-unit-tests-go.

Comment: The page you linked is not too helpful and 5 years old. Maybe there are newer opinions, or even newer regulations/conventions/PEPs available...