# Importing in __init__.py to a unittest package

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I have a package and a test package. According to advice from [Where do the Python unit tests go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151/where-do-the-python-unit-tests-go), the tests should be in a different directory. The project's directory tree is as follows:

```
project\
    kernel\
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
    tests\
        __init__.py
        test1.py
        test2.py
        test3.py
```

I would like to import the `kernel` package to the `tests` package, because that is where `file1.py` and `file2.py` are being tested. Also, I would like to use one `import` statement in the `__init__.py` instead of importing `kernel` again and again in each test.
I tried adding the following to the `__init__.py` file in `tests` and to `test2.py` , `test2.py`  (together and separately), with no success (the first does no harm, the second gives a syntax error):

```
import kernel
import ../kernel
```

I'm using python2.6. From command line all the above happens. When I use Eclipse PyDev, everything magically works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relative imports you're using will only work if the "project" directory is a python package (i.e. it has an `__init__.py` file in it). Try that first and see if that works for you.

If the `kernel` directory is acting as the "package" that would be distributed then you could put the `tests` directory inside of that and do the relative imports that way. So it would look like this:

```
project/
    kernel/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test1.py ...
```

And you would import the kernel modules from the tests directory either as:

```
from kernel import file1  # if it's installed in the python path/environment
```

Or:

```
from .. import file1
# 'import ..file1' might work, but I'm not sure that's syntactically correct
```