# What is the proper way to write unit tests on modules (in subdirectories) which use other modules in the parent directory in Python

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-module, directory-structure

Tried to describe it as best as I could in the title. I'm quite new to using python for a big project. Usually, I only use it for small scripts. I read through the manual and found out what is the proper way to make modules.

So I have the following file structure set up now:

```
- main.py
- module1
  - __init__.py
  - thing1.py
  - thing2.py
- module2
  - __init__.py
  - thingA.py
  - thingB.py
```

My project will run when I start main.py.

I know I can write simple unit tests for every 'thing' by using the `if __name__ == '__main__':` in every one of them which is what I do.

The file thingB.py needs thing2.py to work. As long as main.py is started, thingB will find thing2. But when I start thingB directly (to make its unit test run) in its own directory, it won't find thing2.

What is the proper approach for this?

Comment: Aren't you storing the tests in a separate file? Your description is a bit ambiguous, you say you've read through the manual, I'm assuming the unittest docs, they're quite clear on tests living inside their own modules ([one example](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface)). See also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151/where-do-the-python-unit-tests-go).

Comment: I hadn't read about unit tests no, I was basing this question on [6.1.1 Executing modules as script](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts) which is sufficient for my needs... I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run everything from your main directory:

```
python -m module1.thing1
python -m module2.thingA
```

this way `module1` and `module2` can import from each other. Unit tests should be run in the same way:

```
python -m unittest discover module1
python -m unittest discover module2
```

Comment: That make sense! Great! Thanks!