# Python ModuleNotFoundError when importing a package

Tags: python

I getting and error when I try to import a package from another folder. I have the folowing:

```
project  
|  
|-- main.py  
|  
|-- lib  
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main_class.py
|   |-- global_functions.py
|   |-- cg_api_simple
|   |-- cg_api_status
|  
|-- tests    
    |-- __init__.py  
    |-- test_main_class.py
```

Where my `lib/__init__.py` has:

```
from lib.main_class import PyGecko
```

and my `test/__init__.py` is empty.

When I run `python3 -m unittest test_main_class.py` I get:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_main_class (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_main_class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 154, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/someone/Documents/pythoncoingecko/tests/test_main_class.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib import PyGecko
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I've already tried:

- Add /project and /project/lib to my PYTHONPATH
- Use sys before import
- Add .. before the import
- Try to remove `__init__.py` from both folders

The only time I don't get an error is when I move `test_main_class.py` to where main.py is located. How could I solve this?
You can see more on github

> https://github.com/SrJMaia/pythoncoingecko

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running your unit tests from the "project" directory, rather than from "project/tests"?  I think the *usual* structure is to have `project/src/main/` and `project/src/test` directories, with no actual code in `project/src/`, and having the extra layer between `${PWD}` and the code does seem to help...  but Python's import errors are definitely confusing

Comment: Looks like a similar question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260792/import-a-file-from-a-subdirectory

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. I don't want to move the tests to the same folder as `project/lib`.  I also followed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61151/where-do-the-python-unit-tests-go

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a proper combination of your current working directory, the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and the path to the test.

If you run `python3 -m unittest test_main_class.py` from the `tests` directory, you need to add the `project` directory to `PYTHONPATH`. I.e.:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=.. python3 -m unittest test_main_class.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
$ PYTHONPATH=/tmp/project python3 -m unittest test_main_class.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Or you can run `python3 -m unittest tests/test_main_class.py` from the `project` directory. In that case, you do not need to modify `PYTHONPATH`. I.e.

```
$ python3 -m unittest tests/test_main_class.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I liked your suggestion but I didn't worked. I'm using a temporary fix with try except

Comment: @JMaia, can you elaborate on what it means that it did not work?